# camera crashes when not taking picture

Tags: android, camera

I have a simple activity that when clicking a button, the picture is set to the ImageView.

When I open the camera and take the picture, it is fine and the picture is loaded to the ImageView.
But if I open the camera app via the button, and cancel(press the back button), then the application crashes.
I'd to know how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Activity

```
    import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class SituationStatusActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView imVCature_pic_first;

private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private ImageView imageView;
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
String imageFilePath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_situation_status);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
     imageFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Android/data/com.my.app/Image-"+timeStamp+".png";

    imVCature_pic_first = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nirPic);

    Button uploadPic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.picUploadButton);
    uploadPic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {    /*************************** Camera Intent Start ************************/
            File imageFile = new File(imageFilePath);
            Uri imageFileUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile); // convert path to Uri
            // Standard Intent action that can be sent to have the camera
            // application capture an image and return it.
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageFileUri);   // set the image file name
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            /*************************** Camera Intent End ************************/
        }
    });

}


public void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        //imageFilePath image path which you pass with intent
        Bitmap bp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFilePath, bmpFactoryOptions);

        //rotate image by 90 degrees
        Matrix rotateMatrix = new Matrix();
        rotateMatrix.postRotate(270);
        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bp, 0, 0, bp.getWidth(), bp.getHeight(), rotateMatrix, false);
        imVCature_pic_first.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerBitmap(rotatedBitmap,500));
        imVCature_pic_first.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"not taken", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}


public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap
            .getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    final float roundPx = pixels;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
}
```

LogCat error

```
            java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=0, data=null} to activity {fastner.israel.nir_zabari.onelove/fastner.israel.nir_zabari.onelove.SituationStatusActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3688)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3731)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:162)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5430)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:913)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at fastner.israel.nir_zabari.onelove.SituationStatusActivity.onActivityResult(SituationStatusActivity.java:83)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6299)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3684)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3731) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:162) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5430) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:913) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
```

Comment: Since when did stackoverflow become fix-my-code.com? you should be asking a specific question to understand your problem, not ask us to fix the code for you. It doesn't look like you did any work to try to understand your problem. Show some due diligence, won't ever learn that way.

Comment: You are right. I did not expressed myself clearly. My intent was to understand what is the problem, but in order to fix it. 
I emphasized on making the code work, and not understanding the problem. I did searched in google, went to developer.android, checked other StackOverFlow threads, but did not manage to understand how to fix it (understand the problem, and fix it after understand what is wrong).  @JoxTraex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check `resultCode` along with `requestCode` as for cancelling the camera, you will get null intent data in your `onActivityResult`

Change your code to as below:

```
public void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        //imageFilePath image path which you pass with intent
        Bitmap bp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFilePath, bmpFactoryOptions);

        //rotate image by 90 degrees
        Matrix rotateMatrix = new Matrix();
        rotateMatrix.postRotate(270);
        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bp, 0, 0, bp.getWidth(), bp.getHeight(), rotateMatrix, false);
        imVCature_pic_first.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerBitmap(rotatedBitmap,500));
        imVCature_pic_first.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"not taken", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

PS: try to avoid using hardcoded value for requestCode, declare it as constant variable.

Comment: Thank you for the comment!
Why to avoid using hardcoded value for the requestCode? @Gagan singh

Comment: For better programming practices, hardcoded values should be avoided. For ex, you are using a hardcoded key value for a bundle that is used in multiple places. Now if you want to change that key name, you need to change it to all places where it was using. If you declare it as constant, you just need to change the value of that constant on a single place.

Answer (score 0):

In your onActivityResult method, after checking for requestCode check for resultCode. resultCode returns RESULT_OK if you accepted the image from camera and RESULT_CANCEL if you didn't accept the image from camera. In your case your not accepting any image from camera and coming back to the activity so resultCode will be RESULT_CANCEL. If you wont check condition for resultCode then app will crash.

```
public void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        //imageFilePath image path which you pass with intent
        Bitmap bp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFilePath, bmpFactoryOptions);

        //rotate image by 90 degrees
        Matrix rotateMatrix = new Matrix();
        rotateMatrix.postRotate(270);
        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bp, 0, 0, bp.getWidth(), bp.getHeight(), rotateMatrix, false);
        imVCature_pic_first.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerBitmap(rotatedBitmap,500));
        imVCature_pic_first.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
       }
       else{
            // your code in cancel condition
       }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"not taken", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi.
I'm getting the same issue.
Mainly, I wanted to know how to handle the RESULT_CANCEL part.